# Mysql PDO create single HTML table from two selects statements from same DB table (SQL advice needed)

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have a table that contains rosters.  Each runner has an row with a column for home and away.  I currently use the following to create two selects, however this creates a wonky table (home rows first, then a step to next row for the away).
This is my current SQL:

```
$getrosterhome = "SELECT 
sk.runnerid hskid, 
sk.runnername hskname, 
sk.runnernumber    hsknum, 
sk.teamid hteamid, 
r.rosterid, t.teamname hsktname, 
t.teamname_abbr hsktnamabbr, 
g.gameid, g.game_name from games_rosters r 

join runners sk on ( sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_1 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_2 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_3 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_4 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_5 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_6 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_7 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_8 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_9 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_10 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_11 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_12 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_13 OR sk.runnerid = r.home_runner_14) 
join teams t on t.teamid = r.home_teamid 
join games_played g on g.gameid = r.gameid AND g.gameid = '$_GET[rosterid]' 
where g.game_deleted = 0 AND r.roster_deleted = 0 AND sk.runner_deleted = 0";
$rowh=$pdo->prepare($getrosterhome);
$rowh->execute();

$getrosteraway = "SELECT 
 sk.runnerid askid, 
 sk.runnername askname, 
 sk.runnernumber asknum,
 sk.teamid ateamid, 
 r.rosterid, t.teamname asktname, 
 t.teamname_abbr asktnamabbr, g.gameid, 
 g.game_name from games_rosters r 
 join runners sk on ( sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_1 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_2 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_3 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_4 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_5 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_6 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_7 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_8 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_9 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_10 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_11 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_12 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_13 OR sk.runnerid = r.away_runner_14) 
join teams t on t.teamid = r.away_teamid 
join games_played g on g.gameid = r.gameid AND g.gameid = '$_GET[rosterid]' 
where g.game_deleted = 0 AND r.roster_deleted = 0 AND sk.runner_deleted = 0";
$rowa=$pdo->prepare($getrosteraway);
$rowa->execute();
```

When I loop through the results I cannot make the table align HOME to the left side and AWAY to the right side on one row.  I can get the HOME results OK with blanks on the right then the rows of AWAY come afterwards leaving big gaps in the table.

Is it possible to create one SQL to cover everything in this case?  I am trying nested selects, joins etc but never getting the correct answers.

default is NULL in the games_rosters  table

Here is what I using for the while loop in

```
 </tr>
    <?php while (( $resultshome = $rowh->fetch()) || ($resultsaway = $rowa->fetch())) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php
                           if ( !empty($resultshome) ) { ?>
                      <?php echo $resultshome['hsknum']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="/runner/profiles/runnerprofile.php?runnerid=<?php echo $resultshome['hskid']; ?>"><?php echo $resultshome['hskname']; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $resultshome['hsktname']; ?>
                    </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
                <?php
                }
                else {
                echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>";
                } ?>
                    <td>
                    <?php
                    if ( !empty($resultsaway) ) { ?>
                      <?php echo $resultsaway['asknum']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="/runner/profiles/runnerprofile.php?runnerid=<?php echo $resultsaway['askid']; ?>"><?php echo $resultsaway['askname']; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $resultsaway['asktname']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                else {
                echo "<td></td><td></td>";
                } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

Thanks for reading and I look forward to advice.

Comment: Are you trying to change the visual appearance of your page? Why would you not handle this in your php code or client side?

Comment: Hi, Yes and No.  Yes I would like to make the table as one with HOME & AWAY on the same row as many times as there are folks in the rosters.  The rosters may not be full or even empty.  So I would like the SQL to change to help the issue or fix the while loop for the table.  I am stuck on both.

Comment: So your issue is that there are empty columns in your table between your home and away columns?

Comment: I actually do not know why I am unable to make this work as a whole.  It could well be that is the issue.  I know I can get them all as two seperate things and when I try nested Selects / left joins etc I end up with mixed up info and multiples of results all being wrong.  So I dont know if it is my joins for names from ids that makes my SQL attempts fail, My while loop works yet I do not get what I expect - blank TD if empty and filled TD in the opposing team... I think I have confused myself somewhere and cannot get back on track thus the two selects and fudge above :(

Comment: I'm just having a hard time understanding how your current results are not in the format you intend. From what I understand, your issue is entirely a visual issue: Your tables are appearing in the wrong format(extra empty columns). If it is purely a visual issue and all the content is correct, I would stop trying to change your SQL queries and focus on the PHP you use to render the tables. Looking at your php, you are echoing empty td tags multiple times after this line: `<?php echo $resultshome['hsktname']; ?>`. Is this intended?

Comment: Before you even attempt to solve any php issues, you should ensure that you are actually getting the correct data from your sql database. The format of the data returned from the database is irrelevant, as long all the data you need is there. Note: the 2 select statements are the correct method to access the data. Don't try merging them together(it will just complicate the issue).

Comment: It is intended in as much as I am trying to fake the TD is if ( !empty($resultshome) ) { ?> thus padding it out on the HOME side if blank results (the else {} ) and then filling the AWAY side.  The code above produces all the entries for HOME in neat rows BUT leaving blanks on the AWAY side of the table.  The AWAY rows come at the END of the first loop and not next to each other neatly.  This leaves a gap of 14 blanks on the AWAY side then the rows of AWAY come leaving BLANKS on the HOME side as it fills the AWAY result TD.